# Save RTF data in My Sql database

Tags: vb.net, rtf

Please tell me how to save and show Richtextbox's data in database and retrive it in saved format and which datatype should be used to save that data. i am using vb.net and MY SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BLOB datatype.

Comment: how to save and retrive... ? should i use richtextbox1.rtf ?

Comment: here there is an example on how to insert an image, just adapt to save the rtf: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,6172,15703

Answer (score 3):

if your data contains image/icons or some special symbols then its better to go for BLOB otherwise you can go with varchar datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Your RTF Data feild should be "Memo".

```
private void InsertToMemo()
{
  using (OleDbConnection oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\AD.mdb"))
  {
    OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into Table2 values(1,'" + this.richTextBox1.Rtf + "')", oleDbConn);
    oleDbCmd.Connection.Open();
    oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}

private void ReadFormMemo()
{
  using (OleDbConnection oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\AD.mdb"))
  {
    OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand("select Field1 from Table2", oleDbConn);
    oleDbCmd.Connection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader oleDbDataReader = oleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();
    oleDbDataReader.Read();
    this.richTextBox2.Rtf = oleDbDataReader.GetString(0);
  }
}
```